# Flask RESTful and Angular CORS Error on POST Method

Tags: python, mongodb, rest, flask, cors

I'm trying to submit a form on a Angular Web application using my Flask-RESTful api, but when i click "submit" i have a error with CORS.

## **APP.PY**

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_restful import Api
from flask_cors import CORS
from flask_pymongo import PyMongo
import resources.products

app = Flask(__name__)
CORS(app, resources={r'/*': {'origins': '*'}})

app.config['MONGO_URI'] = "MONGO URI REPLACED PER SECURITY REASONS"
app.config['CORS_HEADERS'] = 'Content-Type'


api = Api(app)
mongo = PyMongo(app)

api.add_resource(resources.products.Products, '/product/')
api.add_resource(resources.products.Product, '/product/<int:productId>')


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

## **products.py**

```
from flask_restful import Resource, reqparse
from flask import Response
from bson import json_util
from random import randint


class Products(Resource):

    def get(self):

        import app

        productsGetAll = app.mongo.db.Products.find()

        resp = json_util.dumps(productsGetAll)

        return Response(resp, mimetype='application/json')

    def post(self):

        import app

        args = reqparse.RequestParser()

        args.add_argument('productName', type=str, required=True,
                          help="productName cannot be empty.")
        args.add_argument('productSKU', type=str, required=True,
                          help="productSKU cannot be empty.")
        args.add_argument('productCategory', type=str, required=True,
                          help="productCategory cannot be empty.")
        args.add_argument('productEAN', type=str, required=True,
                          help="productEAN cannot be empty.")
        args.add_argument('productCostPrice', type=str, required=True,
                          help="productCostPrice cannot be empty.")
        args.add_argument('productSellPrice', type=str, required=True,
                          help="productSellPrice cannot be empty.")
        args.add_argument('productStock', type=str, required=True,
                          help="productStock cannot be empty.")
        args.add_argument('productProvider', type=str, required=True,
                          help="productProvider cannot be empty.")
        args.add_argument('productDescription', type=str)

        data = args.parse_args()

        if data['productCategory'] and data['productCostPrice'] and data['productEAN'] and data['productName'] and data['productProvider'] and data['productSKU'] and data['productSellPrice'] and data['productStock'] and data['productDescription']:

            rId = randint(0, 9)

            data['productSKU'] = ''.join(
                filter(str.isalnum, data['productSKU']))

            idTeste = app.mongo.db.Products.estimated_document_count()

            productsFilterCount = idTeste if idTeste == 0 else app.mongo.db.Products.find(
            ).sort('id', -1).limit(1)[0]['id']
            productsFilterCount = int(productsFilterCount) + 1

            app.mongo.db.Products.insert_one(
                {'id': int(productsFilterCount),
                 'productCategory': str(data['productCategory']),
                 'productCostPrice': int(data['productCostPrice']),
                 'productEAN': int(data['productEAN']),
                 'productName': data['productName'],
                 'productProvider': data['productProvider'],
                 'productSKU': data['productSKU'],
                 'productSellPrice': int(data['productSellPrice']),
                 'productStock': int(data['productStock']),
                 'productDescription': data['productDescription']
                 }
            )

            productReturn = app.mongo.db.Products.find(
                {'id': int(productsFilterCount)})

            resp = json_util.dumps(productReturn)

            return Response(resp, mimetype='application/json')

        else:
            return {'message': 'Cannot post this product. Try again later.'}


class Product(Resource):

    def get(self, productId):

        import app

        product = app.mongo.db.Products.find({'id': productId})

        resp = json_util.dumps(product)

        return Response(resp, mimetype='application/json')

    def delete(self, productId):

        import app

        arqDelete = app.mongo.db.Products.delete_one({'id': productId})

        return {'message': 'Deletado'}

    def put(self, productId):

        import app

        args = reqparse.RequestParser()

        args.add_argument('productName', type=str, required=True,
                          help="productName cannot be empty.")
        args.add_argument('productSKU', type=str, required=True,
                          help="productSKU cannot be empty.")
        args.add_argument('productCategory', type=str, required=True,
                          help="productCategory cannot be empty.")
        args.add_argument('productEAN', type=str, required=True,
                          help="productEAN cannot be empty.")
        args.add_argument('productCostPrice', type=str, required=True,
                          help="productCostPrice cannot be empty.")
        args.add_argument('productSellPrice', type=str, required=True,
                          help="productSellPrice cannot be empty.")
        args.add_argument('productStock', type=str, required=True,
                          help="productStock cannot be empty.")
        args.add_argument('productProvider', type=str, required=True,
                          help="productProvider cannot be empty.")
        args.add_argument('productDescription', type=str)

        data = args.parse_args()

        print(data['productStock'])

        productEdit = app.mongo.db.Products.find_one_and_update(
            {'id': productId},
            {'$set': {'productName': data['productName'],
                      'productSKU': data['productSKU'],
                      'productCategory': data['productCategory'],
                      'productEAN': int(data['productEAN']),
                      'productCostPrice': int(data['productCostPrice']),
                      'productSellPrice': int(data['productSellPrice']),
                      'productStock': int(data['productStock']),
                      'productProvider': data['productProvider'],
                      'productDescription': data['productDescription']
                      }, })

        resp = json_util.dumps(productEdit)

        return Response(resp, mimetype='application/json')
```

Everything runs fine on the GET and DELETE method. but POST, PUT, PATCH still getting CORS error.
I scanned all the internet for possible solutions envolving FLASK_CORS and nothing works. even seting the to any origin (using: '/*') or making a Angular Proxy file..

Comment: what if you just do `CORS(app)` without the extra args?

Comment: im not sure that `/*` matches `/product/<int>` ... maybe it does but i dont know ... meh their `/api/*`  example implies that it does match

Comment: i have tried without extra args, and POST method does't work yet. :/

Comment: "/*" means that will accept any origin on any endpoint. Initially GET method is not working, but now works and POST not.

Answer (score 0):

You likely are having an issue with the preflight request that's being sent, so you need to pass `supports_credentials=True` or `CORS_SUPPORTS_CREDENTIALS=True` in your config.

Here is what a preflight request is:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Preflight_request

Flask CORS discussion:

See here: https://github.com/corydolphin/flask-cors/issues/200

Comment: ahhh nice solve ... i wonder why ive not had to do this historically (at least not that i remember)

Comment: Even passing `CORS(app, resources={r'/*': {'origins': '*'}}, supports_credentials=True)`
still doens't work..

Comment: getting preflight error - anyone have ideas?

Comment: Without seeing your client code nobody can say. I think there's a CORS restriction where you cannot use "localhost" and you cannot have * in your allowed domains  - that might just be for Axios but I can't remember.